# Bootstrap как разместить объкты друг за другом

Tags: html, css, html5, bootstrap

Нужно сделать вот так ПРИ ПОМОЩИ BOOTSTRAP[image: нужныйрезультат]

А получается только так и только[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Карточка 12 колонок а полоса 2 колонки (я знаю что можно только 12 но не могу найти решения).

Comment: Код свой покажете?

Answer (score 1):

Не понятно что нужно, но например так:

```css
.grey {
  background: grey;
  height: 100px;
}

.pink {
  background: pink;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-offset-5 col-xs-2">
        <div class="grey"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="pink"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-offset-5 col-xs-2">
        <div class="grey"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Или так:

```css
.grey {
  background: grey;
  height: 600px;  
}

.pink {
  background: pink;
  height: 300px;
}

.row-rel {
  position: relative;
}

.fix {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row row-rel">
      <div class="col-xs-offset-5 col-xs-2">
        <div class="grey">          
           
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="fix">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="pink"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Cпасибо большое